# how to test if my chrome browser support javascript es9?

Tags: javascript

After having read another similar post that doesn't answer mine, I wonder what is an easy and fast way to know if my Chrome version 68 supports JavaScript ES9 ECMAScript 2018.

Comment: If you [search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=EcmaScript+support&oq=EcmaScript+support+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3311j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you find [a chart](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Answer (score 2):

There will not be a major release of ES9 in any browser. In the past it has always been a feature by feature rollout. This behavior probably has parts of its reasons in the way a ECMAScript standard is developed. Before any feature is moved to the final stage in the standardization process it has to be implemented in at least two independent implementations, typically browsers. So each feature will probably land in the major browsers eventually, but probably even before the standard they belong to is finalized.

For more information see https://tc39.github.io/process-document/ (see notes at Stage 4, finished).

Comment: I wonder if and when will be implemented a statement that when run in any javascript code will show which version is running?

Comment: I would not expect this to happen. As I mentioned each browser implements a specific set of features from the ECMAScript Standard. Each browser has its own pace at this. And as I mentioned each feature has to be implemented by two independant ECMAScript implementations to even reach the necessary stage in the standardization process to become part of a official ECMAScript standard eventually. So the best thing you can do is check for specific features from each proposal that is at least in stage 3 or already officially standardized. This will give you the best picture, I guess.